# DirectX API level vs. feature level

Tags: graphics-card

Two graphics cards have the following DirectX specs, respectively:

- DirectX 11.2 (feature level 11_0)
- DirectX 12 API (feature level 11_0)

What's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In every update of DX there are features that require new hadware and features that are supported by hardware already released.  DX12 isn't an exception.

For example here is the current chart for DX11

[image]

> The purpose of the feature level function is to allow developers to
>   target a single API rather than developing separate codebases in
>   parallel to ensure that a game can run smoothly on multiple
>   generations of GPU hardware rather than writing separate code for
>   DX12, DX11, DX10, and so on. A DirectX 11 GPU with feature level 9_3
>   couldn’t magically perform DirectX 11 effects, but it could run games
>   in DirectX 9 mode without the developer needing to write an entirely
>   separate engine implementation to allow for it.

Most websites that would cover DX12 likely talk about the huge potential performance increases that will come with DX12.  Your current card will support those changes.

> It’s important to remember that the multi-threading and multi-GPU
>   capabilities of DirectX 12 that we’ve seen previewed to-date (and
>   demonstrated via Mantle) are still completely available to every
>   feature level.

[image]

Additionally:

> No current Intel IGP supports DirectX 12_0, while only Nvidia’s
>   Maxwell hardware supports 12_0 or 12_1.

What is slightly different with DX12

> To understand why Microsoft built DirectX 12 the way it did, consider
>   the alternative. Prior to DirectX 11, every new DirectX version was
>   tied to new hardware requirements. From time to time, AMD or Nvidia
>   might implement a specific feature in hardware before it became part
>   of a future DirectX standard, but graphics cards were fixed to the
>   DirectX APIs they supported at launch.

[Source](http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/207598-demystifying-directx-12-support-what-amd-intel-and-nvidia-do-and-dont-deliver])

Comment: Ramhound, your source link is broken.